# How can i change the zoomfactor in cloudzoom?

Tags: javascript

I am using Shopware with integrated Cloud Zoom. I already located the javascript and CSS expressions for Cloud Zoom, but i can´t find an option to change the factor which the images zooms into.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

Just found this question while googling for something similar. For the record, here's how to adjust the CloudZoom parameters. In a JS file (e.g. in your template) use something like this:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.CloudZoom.defaults.zoomWidth = 600;
    $.fn.CloudZoom.defaults.zoomHeight = 370;
    $.fn.CloudZoom.defaults.showTitle = false;
})(jQuery);
```